# How to make static SPA Sveltekit have HTML code in the pages

Tags: single-page-application, cloudflare, sveltekit

I have a project on Sveltekit - a static SPA site. I'll deploy it to Cloudflare Pages which works well.

If I open the site page code, I see the full HTML code, including everything generated using JS. But if I open the `build` folder on my local computer and look at the file, there will be a script there instead of the code that pulls up the layout from JS.

If I deploy the project to an unprepared environment, for example, to the S3 cloud object storage, then I will have the same thing in the page code as on the local computer, because of this, search engines will not see my title, description, OG tags and so on.

Is it possible to make the pages build the same way they end up in Cloudflare, Vercel and others like that?

Comment: Have you looked at the [static site adapter](https://kit.svelte.dev/docs/adapter-static)?

Comment: Yes, sure i use

Comment: Then don't you just have to `prerender` everything?

Comment: So I have `prerender = true`. I just thought it would generate HTML code in static files, and it generates a script that imports chunks of scripts with content... maybe that's how the SPA works

Comment: If you have `ssr` turned off, then yes, everything will be rendered by scripts. Not sure how "transitional" static sites can be, i.e. having mostly static HTML for the first load and still client-side navigation with scripts later.

Comment: Compare two sites http://koltan.beget.tech/ on self-hosted and https://koltan.dev on Cloudflare Pages. Look on code